# Search for the biggest id and add new biggest id in JSON file ( NodeJS )

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

When performing an insert operation i'm trying to add the next biggest id in to JSON file. The thing is that when i have for example id: 13 , it makes new object with id: 14 and rewrites old object with id: 14, after that i have 2 objects with the same id.

What did i wrong ?

```
fs.readFile("DB.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {
    var jsonFileArr = [];   // DB.json objects
    jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data);


    function maxValue(jsonFileArr, prop) { // Searches for the biggest numbers in DB.json
        var max = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonFileArr.length ; i++) {
            if (!max || parseInt(jsonFileArr[i][prop]) > parseInt(max[prop]))
                max = jsonFileArr[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    var maxID = maxValue(jsonFileArr, "id"); //Biggest ID

    console.log("\r\nBiggest ID : " + maxID.id);
    newID = ++maxID.id;

    var updateData = {
        id : newID, // new ID
        name: POST.name,    // Objects that come from POST request when i add new row in the table
        alter: POST.alter,
        produkt: POST.produkt,
        anzahl: POST.anzahl
    }

    jsonFileArr.push(updateData);
    var newUsers = JSON.stringify(jsonFileArr);
    fs.writeFile("JSON/DB.json", newUsers, "utf8");
    console.log("New user has been added with ID : " + newID);
```

Comment: So, your intention is to get the next highest id from the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Written in vanilla Javascript and so should work in Node.js directly.

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  "id": 3,
  "player": "Carmelo Anthony",
  "team": "New York Knicks"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "player": "Andre Drummond",
  "team": "Detroit Pistons"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "player": "Anthony Davis",
  "team": "New Orleans Pelicans"
}]

function getNextId(obj) {
  return (Math.max.apply(Math, obj.map(function(o) {
    return o.id;
  })) + 1);
}


alert('Next ID is ' + getNextId(jsonObj));
```

Comment: @KirillVorobjov glad it cud help.

Answer (score 2):

You return pointer to nested object

```
max = jsonFileArr[i];
```

After that you do

```
newID = ++maxID.id;
```

Which will increase jsonFileArr[i].id property too.

So in order to fix this just do like this

```
newID = maxID.id + 1;
```

Or simply return max.id in function maxValue;

Comment: Thank you for your time and help !)